# Magento Multiple frontName for routers adminhtml

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, adminhtml, router

> Is there any way to assign multiple frontName name for routers adminhtml ?

Basically i have 3 admin role

1. Administrators (default)
2. Salesadmin
3. Sabadmin

now i want to enable admin panel by 3 url

1. /admin (default)
2. /salesadmin
3. /sabadmin

and after login all url should be by whatever user is logged in.

I have below config which is working fine for login but after login url is changed to admin

```
<admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Mage_Adminhtml</module>
                    <frontName>admin</frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
            <salesadmin>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Mage_Adminhtml</module>
                    <frontName>salesadmin</frontName>
                </args>
            </salesadmin>
            <sabadmin>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Mage_Adminhtml</module>
                    <frontName>sabadmin</frontName>
                </args>
            </sabadmin>
        </routers>
 </admin>
```

Comment: Is there any reason not to do this with the default admin roles that magento provides?

Comment: just because client want different url based on role

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this in Magento 1.9 that I know of, without major modification.

In my opinion it's not worth you or your client's time.

I suggest telling your client that it's not possible with the current system. After telling them that educate them on the fact that Magento provides a very robust role management system. Make sure they understand that the role management can restrict certain areas of the website from the specified user type.